# Making output more readable for others

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm trying to make an SQL Query output more readable for our staff. It is a kind of a Warehouse Delivery note. Does not matter if I use Word or Excel or something else.

So I made an SQL Query (MS-SQL 2000 Server), this is working fine. The output obviously is a Table. The first 7 columns containing data that needs to be one time on the print as heading. The next columns containing data that needs to be on a list on the print. Already used PowerPivot to put it in Excel.

To make it some clearer I made a pictures in Excel. The data in the first column contains a "warehouse" number. I need a separate print per Warehouse. As you see,  the first 7 columns also containing data concerning the warehouse. The last 3 columns are the products.

I have to put this:
[image: I have to put this:]

into this, were Column 1 contains the same value. Other value of Column 1 goes to the next page and so on:

[image: into this:]

Answer (score 0):

Return 2 datasets into your excel workbook, one for the heading values and the other for the details.  I'm assuming your first dataset should only return the one row, which means you can reference the values in the data table directly without issue.

Your second table can then be directly inserted into the details section of your spreadsheet and formatted accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, but somehow failed. I divided the table into two tables, one whit the columns 1-7 and the other one whit columns 1 and 8-10. After that I made a Word Serial letter from the Table1, and tried to add the data from the second table. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far it is working now. I used the Grouped Serial Letter function in Word from one Excel Table only. I tried the two Excel table Database Serial Letter version also, but somehow it did not worked. And what did not worked? I dont know, when I run the Database version I only get gibberish output and Errors.

So now I have it that way, that I run a SQL Query, that gives me one Excel Table. After that I run Word and print a Serial Letter